# How to efficiently build and run Teams extension on mobile device

Tags: reactjs, teams-toolkit

I have built a `Teams` extension and would like to build and run on a mobile device so I can test responsiveness.

I can run our deployed application, but cannot build and run a local build. And I cannot deploy every single time I move a pixel.

I tried using `Chrome`'s device toolbar (on my desktop) to emulate mobile device screensizes but it is not at all accurate and doesn't look anything like the deployed build on my `Android`. And if I keep playing with the device toolbar it eventually fails and tells me my browser version is not supported and to download the `Teams` app.

When I open the `Teams` app on my `Android` and try to run the app after building and adding it to my desktop browser it says:

"Something went wrong, and we can't open the AppName app right now"

No description or explanation as to why it failed.

I also tried to share the app (copy URL) from my desktop browser to my phone, but when I click the link on my `Android`, it opens mobile `Chrome` and stays stuck on the "Loading Microsoft Teams" screen for a good few minutes, and eventually pops up an error saying "We're sorry-we've run into an issue".

Again, no description or explanation.

How do I quickly build and run on my mobile device?